# UWP element sizing

Tags: size, uwp

I'm beginner at UWP ,

how can we give sizes to elements that work correctly in both phones and desktop ?

i.e. text block topic must be 200 pixel in desk top and 100 pixel on phones .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve nice and smooth layout behaviour on the phone and desktop.

1. Adaptive triggers
2. DeviceFamily Folders
3. Xaml Behaviors

I published two blog posts about how to achieve good design results:

https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/universal-windows-10-application-with-tailored-design-part-1/

https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/23/universal-windows-10-application-with-tailored-design-part-2/

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/

I also definitely recommend watchin Channel9 video by Dante Gagne about tailored UWP design:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2015-Final-Release-Event/Universal-Windows-Platform-Tailored-Experiences?ocid=SessionsInEvent

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place, where you route traffic to your private blog. Instead, answers should be self-contained, and remain relevant, should the off-site resources become unavailable. Please summarize to key points, in addition to the links.

Answer (score 3):

Read about the [Adaptive Layout in UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)

In a nutshell, you would use the new Adaptive Triggers to change your UI based on the screen width.

```xml
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState  x:Name="Narrow">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyText.Width" Value="100" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState  x:Name="WideScreen">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyText.Width" Value="200" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```